# How can I convert a JarInputStream to a JarFile without saving to disk?

Tags: java, jar

I've got a Servlet on which a user can upload a .jar file to check its `MANIFEST.MF`.

I know the following would work:

```
JarInputStream in = new JarInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream (fileItem.get()));
Manifest mf = in.getManifest();
```

Unfortunately the `getManifest()` method parses for Key: Value and needs the ": " (colon+space), a simple colon is not enough. Since the mobile phones I'm working with also work if the `MANIFEST.MF` only has colons and not colon+space, I'd like to extract the MANIFEST.MF manually, but I don't want to save the file on disk.

If I'd have a JarFile, I could parse the Manifest via:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(fileName);
InputStream in = jarFile.getInputStream(jarFile.getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splitAr = line.split(":", 0);
    // ...
```

But unfortunately I have no idea how I could convert a `JarInputStream` (or a `ByteArrayInputStream`) to a `JarFile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would try to do in this case:

- iterate through all the entries in the jar using `getNextEntry()` -- not `getNextJarEntry()`! and see if you can reach the manifest this way
- try to use a `ZipInputStream` instead which is more generic -- `JarInputStream` in fact extends it -- and that should give you access to get the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only reaching META-INF, but not the files in the directory..

`public void parse(ZipInputStream in) {
  try {
   ZipEntry zipentry =  in.getNextEntry();
   while (in.getNextEntry() != null) {
    System.out.println(zipentry.getName());
    if (zipentry.getName() == "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF") {
     System.out.println("WOHO");
    }
    zipentry = in.getNextEntry();
   }
  } catch (IOException e){
  }
 }`

Comment: when using ZIP you will get 2 entries: META-INF (the directory) and then META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. However, do not test for string equality using == but use instead equals("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")! In fact I would suggest just for testing purposes using equalsIgnoreCase().

Comment: My parse() isn't "descending" into META-INF, it's just giving out META-INF, but not the MANIFEST.MF in it. It's printing .class files in other directories..

Comment: are you creating a ZipInputStream or downcasting the JarInputStream to ZipInputStream? So have you changed the first line to `ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream (fileItem.get()));` ?

Comment: It's
  ZipInputStream in = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream (fileItem.get()));
       parse(in);

Comment: and if you open the jar up with the likes of WinRar/etc you can see the manifest file?

Comment: But it's ok, I've accepted that :_ must be there, I'm giving a warning message if it isn't.

Comment: Oh my... now I need to get it running, since a signed Midlet crashes getManifest, since the dumb function assumes that the Manifest is at the beginning of the stream http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4338238

Comment: I think an "easy" fix would be, to write the JarInputStream to a temporary file, access this file via JarFile and then get the Manifest. Is this possible without writing the temporary file to disk? And if not, any links on what I should read to do that?

Comment: I think I've got it  :)

`public static HashMap<String, String> jarOpen(byte[] in) {
  HashMap<String, String> hashedFile = new HashMap<String, String>();

  try {
   File tempFile = null;
   tempFile = tempFile.createTempFile("tempF", ".tmp");
   OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
   os.write(in);
   os.close();

   JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(tempFile);
   InputStream ind = jarFile.getInputStream(jarFile
     .getEntry("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ind));`

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by the standard API. The only way to construct a `JarFile` is by providing a `File` reference, and since the API does not provide an interface to create "special files" backed by for instance an InputStream, it is not possible to solve it.

If you're on a UNIX system, you could probably set up a [device file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) some how, but you would lose portability.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void copyFiles(JarInputStream in, JarOutputStream out)
    throws IOException
  {
    JarEntry inEntry;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    while ((inEntry=(JarEntry)in.getNextEntry())!=null)
          {if (inEntry.getMethod()==0)
              {out.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(inEntry));
              }
           else
               {out.putNextEntry(new JarEntry(inEntry.getName()));
               }
           //InputStream data=in;//the call to ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() positions the InputStream at the start of the entry and therefore supplying the ZipInputStream is the equivalent of supplying a ZipEntry's InputStream.the ZipInputStream is smart enough to handle the entry's EOF downstream
           int num;
           while ((len=/*data*/in.read(buffer))>0)
                 {out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                 }
           out.flush();
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read manifest from input stream as string an parse it by yourself

```
/**
 * Read JAR  manifest as String from input stream.
 * Like JarInputStream, assume that META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry  should be either 
 * the first or the second entry (when preceded  by the dir META-INF/).
 */
def readManifestAsString(InputStream is) {
    def zip = new ZipInputStream(is);
    def e = zip.getNextEntry();
    if (e != null && e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("META-INF/"))
        e =  zip.getNextEntry();  
    if (e != null && JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getName())) {
        byte[] bytes = getBytes(new BufferedInputStream(zip));
        return new String(bytes, "UTF8");
     }
}

byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
        int n;
        while ((n = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
 }
```

JAR Manifest specification can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest)