# java - Invoke main jar from a jar

Tags: java

I am trying to invoke a main class that is packaged in a jar (B.jar). I am invoking it from java code. This works when I am running it from my IDE. But when I package my code into a jar (A.jar), and then invoke my code from commandline I get exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: no !/ in spec". Here is the code snippet of how I am invoke B.jar from A.jar.

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource(B.jar);
URL[] urls = {resource.toURI().toURL()};
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
URL url =  new URL("jar", "", resource + "!/");
JarURLConnection uc = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// this is where excption is being thrown - "java.lang.NullPointerException: no !/ in spec".
Attributes attr = uc.getMainAttributes();
String mainClass = attr.getValue(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS);
Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(mainClass);
Method mainMethod = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
Object response = mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
```

Comment: How are you importing the B.jar library into your A.jar project? Are you using any build tool like Maven/Gradle? I suspect that B.jar isn't in A.jar classpath, therefore is not visible...

In general, I can't see why you want to invoke the main method... you probably want to create a specific method to be exported to external callers.

Comment: I am using a maven build. The resulting packaged jar (A.jar) I am invoking from a bat file. On your question of invoking main method - not my choice. B.jar is provided from an external source.

Comment: The error seems unrelated to packaging. Try to print out out the URL string you're feeding into the `url` variable, my gut tells me it is against expectations different when run outside of your IDE.

Comment: Looking at the log you refer to, it looks like the `resource` variable is empty... are you sure you're building that path properly? Have you tried printing its value out?

Comment: This is how the url to B.jar is being fed jar:jar:file:/C:/path.../A.jar!/B.jar!

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to extract a jar that is inside another jar. The path jar:file:/C:/path.../A.jar!/B.jar! doesn't look like a valid File Path. Maybe you should load the B.jar using an input stream. This is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803769/how-can-i-convert-a-jarinputstream-to-a-jarfile-without-saving-to-disk